# A way to prevent compilation of SCSS/SASS files without appending _ to their name?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using [Foundation 4 standalone](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/tree/scss-standalone/) as a read-only git submodule in a project, and need combine all of its scss files into an umbrella `project.scss` file, which then gets compiled to `project.css`.

I'm using Compass to compile, however it compiles any scss file not appended with underscore, so both `foundation/scss/normalize.scss` and `foundation/scss/foundation.scss` get compiled twice each - once each standalone, and also into my `project.scss` file that imports both.

Is there any way to prevent compilation besides appending an underscore to `normalize.scss` and `foundation.scss`?  I'd rather not append the underscore b/c I want to use the Foundation standalone project exactly as is from the official repo, and simply import it into the project-specific `project.scss` where all the customizations reside.

Edit:  More explanation - I'm using a Scala framework managed by SBT, which makes a system call to Compass compile via an SBT plugin.  Compass compile still reads `config.rb` in my project root for source and target dirs, but I'm not sure what/if other Compass tricks are available in this setup.

I was rather hoping for some kind of syntax trick in `config.rb` or a Compass command line flag that could tell it to, say, compile all .scss files in `[project root]/sass`, but not recursively, eg, don't compile anything in `[project root]/sass/foundation` or other subdirectories.  Anyone know anything like that?

Comment: Why do you need to use Foundation standalone?

Comment: I'm not using a Ruby framework, I'm using a Scala framework managed by SBT, which compiles SASS via Compass compile called by a plugin.  This got me thinking though, maybe an alternative is to import Foundation into config.rb and see if Compass can compile it that way too.  But then, not sure where to put my project.scss file.  New to Compass, and still feeling my way around integrating these two technologies.

Comment: I still don't see a reason you *can't* use Foundation as a Compass extension (I'm not using Ruby for anything other than Compass/Sass, either), which would solve your entire problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll play with that idea and see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simple: do not include Foundation files into your project.

Instead, install it as a Compass extension and require it from your Compass config.

Note that installing via Gemfile ([bundler](http://bundler.io)) is preferred over installing manually with `gem install`.

Comment: While I agree that this would work, he more likely is just importing foundation twice.  I remember when I just started using scss and did not fully understand what @import did.  I had a 170,000 line css file. Lol

Comment: @Andrey - thanks, but I'm not using a Ruby framework, I'm using a Scala framework managed by SBT which makes a system call to Compass compile via plugin to compile the SASS.  Compass still uses [project root]/config.rb to find out where the SASS source and target dirs are, though.

Comment: @zmanc - haha, nasty surprise.  Pretty sure that's not the case here though, I've got the `@import foundation` line in config.rb commented out though, and I know it's compiling the SASS in my foundation standalone submodule b/c it's also compiling my custom `project.scss` one directory up, which is what I specified in config.rb.

Comment: Basically, I was hoping there would some syntax I could add to `config.rb` or a commandline switch to Compass compile or something that could do this.  Say, compile all .scss files in `[project root]/sass`, but not recursively, eg don't compile anything in `[project root]/sass/foundation`, even stuff that's not appeneded with underscore.

Comment: Compass is Ruby software. If you use Compass, you do have Ruby in your system. Remove Foundation from your project, run `gem install zurb-foundation`, add `require zurb-foundation` to `compass.rb` and add `@import "foundation";` to the beginning of your SCSS code. If you don't believe me, listen to @cimmanon, he's a true SASS expert.